# enqueue dynamic css in wordpress doesn t work

Tags: php, css, wordpress, dynamic

I enqueing a php file to get dynamcis styles on my functions.php in the travelify-child folder

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style_perso', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styleperso.php');}
```

The file is enqueue correctly but it doesn t take the php code

This is  a short exemple of my styleperso.php

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
 $newbgcolor ='red';
$newbgimage = 'none';

?>
body.custom-background {
background-color: <?php $newbgcolor ?>;
background-image: <?php $newbgimage ?>;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top right;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried to put the in the file

```
require '/../../../wp-load.php';
```

But it didn't make any difference.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Possible answer [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/#article-header-id-5).

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to solve this:

**General**

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('dynamic-css', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '?action=dynamic_css', null, null);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');

function dynamic_css_action() {
    include ( 'dynamic-css.php' );
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_dynamic_css', 'dynamic_css_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dynamic_css', 'dynamic_css_action');
```

**dynamic-css.php**

```
<?php
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 86400) . ' GMT');
    header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8');

    $newbgcolor ='red';
    $newbgimage = 'none';
?>
body.custom-background {
    background-color: <?php echo $newbgcolor ?>;
    background-image: <?php echo $newbgimage ?>;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I tried everything but it looks like the                                  wp_enqueue_style('dynamic-css', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') is not done . I checked it out wtih wp_style_is and it is not done...!!!!_

Comment: So could you check if the ajax request works and the file gets loaded with `var_dump`? Note, for the ajax request you must look into your network console inside your devtools.

Comment: Filter headersExpires :Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT

Comment: It seems that it takes a long time to get the ajax for the size of the file (.85kb) and 3146 ms compare 10 ms  but it is in green seemed it worked. I saw that in the Filter headers of the console for the ajax     Expires :Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 gmt   . This is the only thing that seems wrong. For the var_dump i don't know how to use it with this file.

Comment: So the file 'dynamic-css.php' is acting exactly as if it was a .css file

Comment: I've updated my code. Please try again, it should now cache it.

Comment: thank you very much for everything. It looks that the only thing to do is to add an echo to  background-color: <?php echo $newbgcolor ?>;